# Ordering an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

[image]

It has 16 positions and each position is an object with an ID and a content. I have to order this array alphabetically by it's content. I tried to use sort, but it didn't work. Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Please always, always, always include the code you are asking about as text, not pictures of text. And, show what you've tried (even if it didn't work).

Comment: Please show code and data as text, not as a picture of text. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2))` to get a good representation, then copy a representative portion of that data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the sort method like that:

```
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.content - b.content;
});
```

Or using ES6:

```
elems.sort((a, b) => a.content - b.content);
```

Comment: OP says he/she needs to sort by content (not ID) and are you sure about that `-`?

Comment: Sure... I've fixed but i've added the code only as an example how he should implement the sort. Btw, thanks for check it :D